# How to hide the UITableview footer view initially?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have requirement to show a message as "No notification" when the array is empty but once the array is with data then remove the footer view and display the data in tableview.I followed the below method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
if(self.notificationDataArray.count == 0){
    self.tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = NO;
    return 50;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(self.notificationDataArray.count == 0){
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section]);
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame];
    [view addSubview:textLabel];
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueTextColor];
    textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    textLabel.text = @"No Notification";
    return view;
} else {
    return nil;
}

}
```

But initially before the API call,the array will be empty so the Footer view appears for a fraction of seconds and then disappears.How to initially hide the footer view,i mean before the tableview is loaded.Could anyone suggest me a solution for it,
Thank u.

Comment: Hide it in videDidLoad ?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = YES;}..i tried this but in vain,it appeared again for a fraction of seconds

Comment: Why not just hide the whole tableView until you have data?

Comment: i tried the above method,but the screen looks black when tableview hidden.....

Comment: if the screen look black it means no view was pushed so you need to change the view background color to white not clear color

Comment: You can declare a bool variable initially no and check it with your if conditions using logical and operator. So for the first time it will be false and no footer will appear. After api call when your received data then set the bool variable to yes and then reload the table.

Answer (score 3):

on View did load you do like this before the Api call.

```
yourTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;

[[yourTableView tableFooterView] setHidden:YES];


-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if ([yourArray count]==0) {

        return nil;
    }
    return yourCustomView;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    if ([yourArray count]==0) {

        return 0;
    }
    return yourCustomViewHeight;

}
```

then after getting the response,you could show up the footer view, change the values as you needed

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section]);
if(self.notificationDataArray.count == 0)
{
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame];
    [view addSubview:textLabel];
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueTextColor];
    textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    textLabel.text = @"No Notification";
 } 
 else 
 {
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 }
return view;
}
```

Expect this you can also hide tableview when array count is zero, and you can also hide footer initially in your viewdidLoad method.

Comment: Above code does not hide the footer view  initially,and hiding footer view in viewDidload also did not work out for me..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a BOOL instance variable to indicate the loading of data.

```
BOOL dataLoaded;
```

Initialy in `viewDidLoad` set it to `NO`. And after loading the data you can make it as YES.

```
dataLoaded = YES
```

Now the checking condition would be

```
if(self.notificationDataArray.count == 0 && dataLoaded){
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont return nil instead initialize a blank view with 0 frame and return that

```
if(self.notificationDataArray.count == 0){
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section]);
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame];
    [view addSubview:textLabel];
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueTextColor];
    textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    textLabel.text = @"No Notification";
    return view;
} else {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return view ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set the text in the titleForFooterInSection. Empty if the item count is 0.
The text will not be shown when the table loads.

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section   {

```
NSString *mensaje = @"";
NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section ];

if (numberOfRowsInSection == 0) {
    mensaje = @"No notifications";
}

return mensaje;
```

}